# Entirely deleted "App.xaml" and created own entry point, What are the consequences?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I just removed the "App.xaml" entirely from my solution and created my own xamlless entry class where I'm implementing the traditional static `Main()` method.

I'm instancing a new `Application` class and setting it up before calling its `Run()` method, giving it a `StartupUri`, As well adding to it a new resource-dictionary so my styles are applied automatically. Everything works as intended, the main window shows up, the resources are loaded and the templates are properly applied on all controls and windows.

But I need to know if there are any bad consequences by doing that? What did that `App` class offer me so I should keep it instead of replacing it by my own compact and xamlless entry point that gave me the same exact result?

```
public static class Entry
{
    private static readonly Application _application = new Application();
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        _application.StartupUri = new Uri( "/Eurocentric;component/Interface/MainWindow.xaml" , UriKind.Relative );
        var style = new ResourceDictionary
                    {
                    Source = new Uri( "/Eurocentric;component/Interface/Styles/VictorianStyle.xaml", UriKind.Relative )
                    };
        _application.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add( style );
        TemplatedWindow.Defaults();
        _application.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Counter question:  What are the positives in doing this?

Comment: All explained in the Remarks section of the [Application Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Application.aspx) page on MSDN, especially in `Note: A standalone application does not require an Application object; it is possible to implement a custom static entry point method (Main) that opens a window without creating an instance of Application. However, XAML browser applications (XBAPs) require an Application object.`

Comment: @Clemens That doesn't list the negatives (if any) of doing so however

Comment: It answers your second question, "What did that App class offer me so I should keep it instead of replacing it by my own compact and xamlless entry point that gave me the same exact result?". If there were any negatives (besides that XBAPs require an Application object), I'm pretty sure they would also be listed there.

Comment: Behind the scenes, app.xaml is doing exactly what you did any way. That is why the property of app.xaml is application definition. It makes no difference at all in either case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the `App` class in the decompiler reveals this autogenerated method in the `App` class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Application Entry Point.
/// </summary>
[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
public static void Main() {
    RootNamespace.App app = new RootNamespace.App();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Run();
}
```

So, I'd say, there's no difference in terms of what happens at runtime. It affected our development experience, though.

I've also used the manual approach myself and the one downside I saw is that ReSharper does not pick up application-wide resources, so they're not available in the XAML code completion and there're great number of warnings because of it. To mitigate it I've had to add a fake App.xaml file to the project. ReSharper specifically searches for a .xaml file with the `ApplicationDefinition` build action, so you can keep the entry point different to satisfy both ReSharper and the need to use a custom entry point.

One other thing, you can see here that's unlike other .xaml files is that the `InitializeComponent` method is called separately instead of being called in the overriden constructor. So if you'll ever decide to use the XAML-backed Application class in your custom entry point, you'll either need to call this method separately too, or add a constructor override that does this because it's not created by default.